# How to connect two bitcoin nodes running globally

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, nodes

I have two nodes running in different PC-s they have different IP-s. I want to connect one node to another with -addnode or -connect arguments. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you answered your own question? You can use addnode=IP if you want to connect to a specific node as well as others, or connect=IP if you *only* want to connect to that one node and no others. Just add it to your configuration file.

Comment: But which IP I should use because now when I am doing it and after checking with 'getaddednodeinfo' there is no connection.

Comment: Make sure the correct port is open/forwarded if it's behind a firewall, perhaps try to ping one machine from the other to see if there is a connection